# Return empty resultset depending on value of variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Short and easy question for the likes of you guys, I'm sure...

I have a stored proc that takes in a variable @iLevel. I want to make sure that @iLevel is always lower than 5.

If it is >= 5, I want to immediately return an empty result set.

I have

```
IF @iLelel >= 5

RETURN 

ELSE

BEGIN

--all my good processing stuff
```

This however just returns nothing. I would like to have an empty resultset sent back.

How do you do this in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I am running the stored proc within SQL Server, and right now, if I run it with my var being lower than 5, I see the result in the messages window. All column names etc. If I run it with my var being 5 or more, the messages window just says, 'Command(s) completed successfully'.

I'm thinking that I would at least want an empty result sent back, not just void.

Could be I'm wrong... Can you tell how new this is to me?

Thanks again!

Comment: SAY `SELECT ''` before `RETURN`. Or if you have list of columns then mentioned `SELECT '' as col1, '' as col2, .... '' as coln`

Comment: @Murtaza That won't produce an empty result set.

Comment: I would ask why you even call the stored procedure is you know from calling application that the value of `@iLelel` is >= 5?

Comment: Yep, that is a good question. My best answer is.... I was told to.

I know that is a crappy answer, but sometimes it just is what it is.

Comment: Can u give example by meaning Empty results set?

Comment: You can create a temp table with no records and select from temp table (ofcourse same columns) Then select from that temp table.

Comment: Just add false "where" condition to your final select - like " ... and @iLevel < 5" and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyProc 
  @iLelel  INT 
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
              -- before you do anything do your test here 
                IF (@iLelel >= 5)
                 BEGIN
                    RAISERROR('Value out of range, greater than 5 blabla',16,1)
                 END
        -- any code here will only be executed if passed the above test              
          -- all of the good stuff here     

    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH
         -- Error handling here 
         -- Log error do what ever you want to do  

    END CATCH

END
```